# What is a very very famous example of structural estimation?

Tags: macroeconomics, microeconomics, risk, structural-estimation

I took a behavioral econ class and learnt the "structural estimation" of risk-aversion parameter.

Later some friends told me that what I learnt is too simple when I was bragging about my term paper in structural estimation. They said structural estimation is much, much more complicated than that.

I understand that behavioral econ is only a small field. I later learnt that structural estimation is also applied in international econ, [accounting](https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=4336916), [corporate finance](https://finance-faculty.wharton.upenn.edu/luket/wp-content/uploads/sites/10/2017/04/Structural_estimation_2017.pdf). I am interested in:

1. A rigorous methodology paper on structural estimation. Preferable include some prominent example that had a great impact on human history.

If there is no such paper, I am most interested in:

2. An example structural model whose importance influenced human history (or economic history at least).

Estimating risk-aversion parameter is very impactful I think. I am looking for a historical work that is both not too simple and several order of magnitude more impactful than that. The Roy model on wage and relocation is impactful, but too simple. My **criteria** of simpleness is that the decision must be determined with two or more factors, not just one. In the Roy model, the worker will relocate if and only if $w_2+\epsilon-C>w_1$: this is a single-factor decision model where the worker only care about money, which is too simple.

Note, guys on AEA has suggested:

1. Highly recommend this book by Ken Wolpin : https://mitpress.mit.edu/books/limits-inference-without-theory

Comment: how do you define most famous? Highest number of citations?

Comment: @1muflon1 Sure, why not. I think "one" of the most famous work is fine. No need to be that strict

Comment: I don't know if there are famous examples but, if I wanted to find one, I'd probably look at  "Structural Macro-Econometrics" by Dejong and a co-author whose name escapes me.